# CFUPDATE - Updating the database

Tags: mysql, database, coldfusion

A pretty newbie question again.
I have a form that retrieves record values for updating.

It pulls through records fine however when I click the update button, you are taken to the action page where it displays the success message. However no data has been updated in the database it self?

```
    <CFUPDATE Datasource="XXXXX" Tablename="Suppliers">
UPDATE Suppliers
SET SupplierName=?,
    Address1=?,
    Address2=?,
    City=?,
    WHERE SupplierCode = #txtSupplier#
</CFUPDATE>
```

Is this the wrong set up? Im a little unsure how to pass the primary key so that may be the error here!

I am capturing data in this way:

```
<CFQUERY name="GetRecord" datasource="XXXX">
SELECT SupplierName, Address1, Address2, City, PostCode, SalesRepName, SalesRepPhone, SalesRepEmail, PaymentTerms, Notes
FROM Suppliers
WHERE SupplierCode = '#txtSupplier#'
</CFQUERY>
<cfoutput>
<H4>You can update supplier details here. Please note, any fields containing characters not permitted will display an error</H4>
<form action="supplier_updated.cfm?code=#txtSupplier#" method="post">
<input type="Hidden" name="SupplierCode" value="#txtSupplier#"><br>
Update Supplier Name:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME "SupplierName" VALUE="#Trim(GetRecord.SupplierName)#">
<BR>
<P>The Supplier Code for the Supplier you wish to edit is: #txtSupplier#</P>
<BR>
Address Line 1: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME "Address1" VALUE="#Trim(GetRecord.Address1)#" SIZE="35" MAXLENGTH="100">
<BR>
Address Line 2: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME "Address2" VALUE="#Trim(GetRecord.Address2)#" SIZE="35" MAXLENGTH="100">
<BR>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<cfupdate>` is not designed to contain SQL. Just use this:

```
<cfupdate datasource="XXXXX" tablename="Suppliers" />
```

and make sure that your form field names match the table column names. ColdFusion will create the appropriate UPDATE statement for you.

It will figure out what columns you want to update by comparing form field names with table column names. It will also figure out the table's primary key and use that in the `WHERE` clause.

Note that `<cfupdate>` is made for very simple situations. It is an easy way to update a basic table, but it might not always be the best fit for what you intend to do.

If you want more control over the update statement, use `<cfquery>` and `<cfqueryparam>`.

```
<cfquery datasource="XXXXX">
  UPDATE
    Suppliers
  SET
    SupplierName = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.SupplierName#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />,
    Address1     = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Address1#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />,
    Address2     = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Address2#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />,
    City         = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.City#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />,
  WHERE
    SupplierCode = <cfqueryparam value="#txtSupplier#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
</cfquery>
```

Also note that `?` generally is *not* the way to specify parameters in ColdFusion. That's what `<cfqueryparam>` is for.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the basic CFupdate but it still doesnt seem to be updating? Is this because I may not be passing the PK correctly?

Comment: Ive updated the question with the 'form gathering' info from my 'submit' page

Comment: @ez87: I'm not sure why, of all things, you'd want to update the `Supplier` as a result of a purchase success. What exactly should happen with this code?

Comment: The supplier is the name of the table the details are in? oh dear wrong copy! Ill update :P

Comment: Have you tried filling in the `formFields` parameter? See [the documentation of `<cfupdate>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c6a.html).

Comment: Ive entered: <cfupdate datasource="XXXX" tablename="Suppliers" /> on the action page. I dont understand as I thought the CFUPDATE matched fields automatically?

Comment: @ez87 Normally it does. That's why I said "have you tried?". Do you get any error from that page?

Comment: Sorry, It wont go through at all. I get the success message but nothing has been updated in the database?

Comment: @ez87 Maybe the error is someplace else. Rewrite the statement as `<cfquery>` and see if that changes anything. Also, is the `SupplierCode` field marked as the primary key of the table in the database?